# call functions passed as props one after another in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a component in React that receives 2 functions as props, they work pretty well. However, I need to call them one after another, as promises. By now I am calling them as:

```
this.props.function1();
this.props.functions2();
```

But they are called in parallel, I tried:

```
let whenfirst =this.props.function1();
whenfirst.then(this.props.function2());
```

But then I get: TypeError: `whenfirst is undefined`

I really cannot make modifications over function1, so how is the easy way to execute the function2 after function1 is completed?

Comment: Are you sure both `function1` and `function2` return Promises?

Comment: @DMan no! indeed no. They don't

Comment: Can you show what's inside those functions? Do they make AJAX calls or something? I'm a bit confused because normally functions are executed one after another anyways, so there must be something inside each function that makes them execute in parallel.

Comment: Assuming `function1` has some asynchronous call, doesn't return promise and doesn't have a callback that you can pass as argument then there is nothing you can do to make them execute one after another.

Comment: @DMan yes, the first one send a POST request, I didn't post that code because that function is using multiple objects and jumping between so many files and is hard to post it.

Comment: If you really can't change `function1` you can at least [delay the execution](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) of `function2` so long that it will, in most cases (but NOT guarantied) execute after `function1` is done. Something like `setTImeout(function2, 4000)`, to delay `function2` with 4 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: Sorry, I missed the crucial part where you said you can't change function1. **Ignore the rest**.

So I'm **guessing** `function1` looks something like this

```
function function1() {
   // make the POST call
   someAJAXLibrary.post('someUrl', maybePostData);
   // Do nothing.. post is doing its work and maybe 
   // you didn't care about the return
}
```

Which means you can't know when the POST call is done. But the library POST call **probably** does return a Promise (that's pretty standard), you just don't use it.

So instead do

```
function function1() {
       return someAJAXLibrary.post('someUrl', maybePostData);
}
```

Now you can use it like you first thought, in your component.

```
let whenfirst = this.props.function1();
whenfirst
   .then(useMeOrNot => this.props.function2());
```